# O2 near magnets?

Tags: magnetism

Now we know that $\ce{O2}$ is paramagnetic. I was just curious to know if we can find $\ce{O2}$ in gaseous state near magnets (of sufficiently strong intensity)? Or is it just that $\ce{O2}$ displays paramagnetism in liquid state only?

Comment: Indeed, gaseous $\ce{O2}$ is paramagnetic as well. As to your first question, we live on a planet with oxygen-rich atmosphere, so $\ce{O2}$ can be found pretty much everywhere even without magnets.

Comment: Yes - if you put a magnet in a room, theoretically, there would be more O2 near the magnet than further away from it. However, you need a pretty darn strong magnet to make the effect even barely noticeable, which is why we don't die when there's a magnet on the other side of the room from us.